# go clean -i ./... works in go 1.14 but doesn't in go 1.20, how to run then?

Tags: go

When I run from go 1.14 `/home/art/tests/go/go-14/bin/go clean -i ./...`

It works fine! However nothing from the list below works for go 1.20 and results in `pattern ./...: directory prefix . does not contain main module or its selected dependencies`:

`/home/art/tests/go/go-20/bin/go clean -i ./...`

`/home/art/tests/go/go-20/bin/go clean  ./...`

`/home/art/tests/go/go-20/bin/go clean -r ./...`

How `go clean` should work in go 1.20?

Comment: You need to run `go clean` from within your module

Comment: @JimB no support for "./..." anymore?! What if I would like to run `go generate ./...` or `go test ./...` will it now be just without `./...`?

Comment: Using `./...` works just fine, but go modules are used by default, and basically required for any external dependencies. The error is telling you the current directory isn't a go module

Comment: @JimB yeah, I don't have a go.mod file there, only GOPATH, isn't then having GOPATH alone sufficient to be able to run with `./...`?

Comment: GOPATH has been deprecated for years, tooling all assumes modules. If you want to force the use of GOPATH, use `GO111MODULE=off`

Comment: @JimB thanks, that make sense, if you wish you could post your answer and i'll accept it